# drag and drop not working on first time but second time yes

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

My problem is that I have an image that I can drag and drop by cloning. The location of these images was automatically saved to a sqlite database from where I can read their position. But when I want to move an element again, the first function does not call the appropriate functions. (dragElement, elementDrag, etc.) This was created from the following link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_draggable. 
But the second time they are called they are working properly.
What could cause such an issue?

The html code:

```
<style>
    .dragicons {
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
    .dropmap {
        position: relative;
        width: 570px;
        height: 570px;
        background-image: url("");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
    }
</style> 

<div class="dragicons">Add new fixture:
<img id="bulb" src="lightbulb.jpg" draggable="true"
ondragstart="dragStart(event)"
width="17" height="24"></div>
<br>
<div id="mapcontainer" class="dropmap" ondrop="dragDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" onmousedown="clickedElement(event)">
</div>
```

Where I read the saved images:

```
bulbs=payload.value;//JSON.parse(payload.value);
for(var i=0;i<bulbs.length;++i){
    icon=document.createElement('img');
    icon.src="lightbulb.jpg";
    icon.height="24";
    icon.width="17";
    icon.draggable=true;
    icon.ondragstart=dragStart;
    iconStyle = document.createElement('style');
    iconStyle.type = 'text/css';
    icon.posX = bulbs[i].pos_x;
    icon.posY = bulbs[i].pos_y;
    iconStyle.innerHTML='.cssClass'+(MapContainer.childElementCount+1).toString()+'{ position: absolute; left: '+bulbs[i].pos_x+'px; top: '+bulbs[i].pos_y+'px; }';
    console.log(iconStyle.innerHTML);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(iconStyle);
    icon.className='cssClass'+(MapContainer.childElementCount+1).toString();
    icon.id='icon'+(MapContainer.childElementCount+1);
    MapContainer.appendChild(icon);
}
```

This is the function which is not called first:

```
function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
 }
```

Comment: If this is just a mental experience on programming, then I can easily say that your bug comes from the fact that you did not take into account all the parameters of this work

Comment: Sorry, but I develop in node-red and many information came from other nodes, but I can provide some code... https://jsfiddle.net/VidarHUN/p1a80zen/

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: that's over 300 lines of code to look at. It's way too much. you should ask your questions here with a sample code minimum. read => https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example